# Error 'specified cast is not valid' con Firestore listener

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-snapshot

Implemente un Listener para optimizar las notificaciones en tiempo real y de ese modo actualizar el icono (tienes notificaciones nuevas).

El método `Listener` efectivamente se gatilla cada vez que se agrega un dato a la coleccion, y contiene lo siguiente:

```
                    database.Collection("Usuarios")
                    .Document(VarGlobal.gIdDoc)
                    .Collection("Notificaciones")
                    .AddSnapshotListener(this);
```

Pero en el método `OnEvent` que contiene lo siguiente:

```
    var snapshot = (DocumentSnapshot)value;
    ...
    ListaIDs.Add(snapshot.Get("Id").ToString());
    ...
```

Me da un problema en la primera linea:

> Linea: var snapshot = (DocumentSnapshot)value;

> Error: Specified cast is not valid.

Lo raro es que si le pongo un punto de interrupción en modo de depuración y reviso el `value` encuentro el Id que estoy esperando.

**Cual es la forma correcta de leerlo?**

[image: Id]

Comment: `ListaIds` es una lista de tipo string?

Comment: Así es. Es una lista para almacenar el Id de la notificacion entrante para no tener que hacerlo luego cuando se quiera visualizar esa notificacion.  -- Pero ni siquiera llega hasta ahi, es en el cast de la primera linea que da error. En la lectura del snapshot.

Comment: `value` es un `QuerySnapshot` (colección de documentos) no se puede castear a `DocumentSnapshot` porque esta clase representa documentos individuales

Comment: Pero tambien ya lo intente con QuerySnapshot. Lo puedes ver en la foto adjunta arriba y sigo sin poder leer el ID.

Comment: Tenias toda la razon @SinneroftheSystem, fui un tonto, el problema era que (como estaba probando) puse el casteo de QuerySnap, pero no quite el de DocSnap y me tiraba el mismo error, por lo que pense me daba el mismo error. No estaba poniendo mucha atencion. Para leer el Id lo hice de esta forma:  

var data = (QuerySnapshot)value;

string cadena = data.Documents[1].Id.ToString(); //Esto es opcional. Lo editare.

Pon tu respuesta para aceptarla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` es un `QuerySnapshot` (colección de documentos) no se puede castear a `DocumentSnapshot` porque esta clase representa documentos individuales. Si quieres acceder al último documento, puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
var data = (QuerySnapshot)value;
var lastIndex = data.Documents.size() - 1;
var snapshot = data.Documents[lastIndex];
```